# DataStructure algorithm for pathfinding in a pointcloud

Tags: c#, data-structures, path-finding

I was unsure how to phrase the title. I am searching for good data structure / algorithm combination for the following problem:

I have about 20000 objects, each containing a set of values (integers) and a XYZ-Position (doubles). I want to find the object that fits the following conditions best:
1. Needs to be within a maximum distance from a given starting point
2. From a given starting point, it has to be reachable by requiring no "hopping" (i.e. "travelling" from one object with position XYZ to another object's position) with a distance greater than a given threshold
3. It has to have the maximum value (of a given position in the set of integers)

At first I thought about graph theory and pathfinding, but it does not seem to fit well. I have no distinct edges, so I would have to link every point with every other point and use the distance as a weight on the edge. This would result in a lot(!) of edges. Second problem is that pathfinding (if I am not mistaken) only takes one criteria (usually distance or costs) as search criteria. But I would need multiple criteria (distance, hop limit, int value).

Any thoughts and also any good libraries to solve this well?

Comment: For stuff like this it really helps if you provide a small example case. There are a few things unclear for me, you seem to imply that some "jumps" (so going from some node A to a node B when node B is further away then some threshold) are not allowed. But later on you claim that if you had to make a graph all nodes would be connected implying you're allowed to travel from any node directly to any other node. That said keep in mind opinion based and library advise questions are not for stackoverflow. Best is to create code and then ask when it doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to be a bit more precise:
I have a list of Star Systems which have a XYZ-Position. Each StarSystem has Prices for different Commodities. I want to be able to search the most profitable route from a given Star System so my profit is maximized. However, different space ships have different jump ranges (roughly from 5 to 200) and a fuel limit (overall distance) so I cannot construct a one-fits-all-graph.

My initial thought was to use a graph, but the variable jump length and the problem that I have multiple values per star systems made me question it.

Comment: Ok, inportant question would be if the starship has to return to the place it started? But in general it sounds like something that should be solvable by linear programming. There should be a lot available to help with that (though I myself have no experience with any linear programming software packages and/or libraries)